# How to delete specific coreData object from TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

So I'm trying to delete data from a `tableView`, which It will delete the cell at the row, but it won't delete the information from coreData, causing it to load again when I call a `.reloadData()`.  I'm really new to coredata and I don't know how to select a specific `Recipe` item that I make.

Here's where I handle the delete:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        recipes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    }

}
```

Here's how I am creating the items in coreData, if this helps.  Also, I have a Git repository [here](https://github.com/Wsoren1/Recipe-Manager) if anyone's willing to look that deep

```
@IBAction func createNewRecipeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newRecipe = Recipe(context: context)
        newRecipe.title = recipeTitleTextBox.text
        newRecipe.instructions = recipeInstructionsTextBox.text
        newRecipe.time = recipeTimeTextBox.text
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current removal method merely deletes the recipe from the storage array. You need to tell the context to get rid of it as well…

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        let recipe = recipes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        guard let moc = recipe.managedObjectContext else { return }
        moc.delete(recipe)
        moc.processPendingChanges()
    }
}
```

You might also want to look into using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. There are several tutorials around.